# Need to retrieve a value from alertDialog

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite DataBase and I need to store some values that I put into an AlertDialog.

This is my code:

```
 boton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final TextView asd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput1);
                final String uI1 = userInput.getText().toString().trim();

                final EditText userInput1 = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput2);
                final String uI2 = userInput1.getText().toString().trim();

                final EditText userInput2 = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput3);
                final String uI3 = userInput2.getText().toString().trim();

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Aceptar",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                        asd.setText(uI1);
                                       if(db != null){
                                           db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuarios (nombre, apellidos, localidad) " +
                                                   "VALUES ('" + uI1 + "', '" + uI2 + "', '" + uI3 + "')");



                                       }
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
```

The TextView is to check if the value Im getting is wrong but Im getting an empty String in both sides, the TextView and in the database value, what am I missing? The references to dialog.xml are just fine, I have 3 EditTexts named editTextDialogUserInput1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values inside onclick method.
Put these kind of lines inside `onclick()`

```
final String uI1 = userInput.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex, Google suggests using DialogFragment instead for these scenarios which will make the code a little easier to read in my opininon. 
But assuming you stick to this method, you need to put 
final String uI1 = userInput.getText().toString().trim();

```
            final String uI1 = userInput.getText().toString().trim();
            final String uI2 = userInput1.getText().toString().trim();
            final String uI3 = userInput2.getText().toString().trim();
```

inside of the onlick method

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                final String uI1 = userInput.getText().toString().trim();
                final String uI2 = userInput1.getText().toString().trim();
                final String uI3 = userInput2.getText().toString().trim();
    ...
    }
```

The main reason for this is that you need to evaluate what is in the TextEdit ONLY after the user click 'Acceptar'. The way you have it, the value of "", which exists in the TextEdit as soon as the OnCreate is loaded, is saved in the Final String. Everything that you type in  is irrelevant thereafter since the value of "" has already and will always be saved as soon as the view is created.

I have not tested it out yet but I don't think you can use Final on the TextEdit or at least should not, since it needs to be mutable. I could be wrong here but I have just never used final with a TextEdit.

Comment: Alex, use the debugger and make it your best friend. If you put break points right around where you think the problem is happened and run in debug, you can see the values of variables at that point. If you see that the values are not lining up, you can put break points before that line and trace where the anamoly happens. If the values do line up, add more break points later to see where it is deviating from the expectations. That has helped me a lot especially when I am at the 6th and 7th hours of coding. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I will start using it.